# How can I split string to list array by using regrex, the different between regexr.com match and regrex match in JS?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have example like this: https://regexr.com/49sdt
As you can see it found 11 elements. Now I would like to split them which only contains list of items begin [Sample .... sample2]

You can check out my code at here: https://repl.it/repls/PriceyNecessaryProfiles
As you can see it has 23 elements.

My expected output like that:

```
[ 'Sample\n•\tThis is sample 1\n•\tThis is sample 2',
  'Sample2\n•\tThis is sample 1\n•\tThis is sample 2',
  'Sample3\n•\tThis is sample 1\n•\tThis is sample 2',
  'Sample4\n•\tThis is sample 1\n•\tThis is sample 2',
  'Sample5\n•\tThis is sample 1\n•\tThis is sample 2',
  'Sample6\n•\tThis is sample 1\n•\tThis is sample 2',
  'Sample7\n•\tThis is sample 1\n•\tThis is sample 2',
  'Sample8\n•\tThis is sample 1\n•\tThis is sample 2',
  'Sample9\n•\tThis is sample 1\n•\tThis is sample 2',
  'Sample10\n•\tThis is sample 1\n•\tThis is sample 2',
  'Sample11\n•\tThis is sample 1\n•\tThis is sample 2' ]
```

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string at `/\n*\d+\.\s*/g` to get the `samples` to individual array items. Use `slice` to remove the empty strings at the beginning and the end of array.

```js
const rawData = `1. Sample
• This is sample 1
• This is sample 2

2. Sample2
• This is sample 1
• This is sample 2

3. Sample3
• This is sample 1
• This is sample 2

4. Sample4
• This is sample 1
• This is sample 2


5. Sample5
• This is sample 1
• This is sample 2

6. Sample6
• This is sample 1
• This is sample 2

7. Sample7
• This is sample 1
• This is sample 2

8. Sample8
• This is sample 1
• This is sample 2

9. Sample9
• This is sample 1
• This is sample 2

10. Sample10
• This is sample 1
• This is sample 2

11. Sample11
• This is sample 1
• This is sample 2
`
let output = rawData.split(/\n*\d+\.\s*|\n$/g).slice(1, -1)
console.log(output)
```

Comment: An additional `\n` is at end of last element of array.